# ZIP is stuck with a garbage file

Tags: command-line, zip

I usually like to thoroughly research my problems before having to ask the community. But now I am stuck. I am using the following command:

```
zip -ur zipfile.zip /volume1
```

In order to backup my whole volume1 directory into another volume. Yes, I know this is not the perfect method for backups but it is just what I need, or basically what my boss needs.

When I run this command manually it is running perfectly, but when I am running it through a python script, I can clearly see on the target machine that the command is running (checked via `top`) but a garbage file with some odd name is created and even though the command is still running but nothing happens anymore, no zip file created, no nothing. Only the command running and a useless created garbage file.
The goal is just to copy some users files, to a zip file, we don't care about directory structure or anything we just need user specific files to be backed up from the shared volume1 to our backup hard disk.

What might have led to this?

Comment: Zip is not good for backing up the Linux filesystem as it does not preserve permissions. Use `tar` or `rsync` instead. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/full_system_backup_with_rsync

Comment: It think you (or your boss) are looking for disk imaging / cloning and there are a number of tools for that like Clonezilla, the only reason one could have to preserve the entire OS structure, software and settings instead of just backing up personal/user files. Neither ZIP nor any of the other file compression tools are really good for that. Maybe if you post your intended goal someone may suggest a better alternative.

Comment: ok edited the question

Answer (score 4):

**Suggested solution:** Try to zip each directory separately, and for sure, don't try to recursively zip all files under `/`

**Detailed answer:**

[zip's manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/zip.1) explain the option you used, e.g. `-r` means:

```
-r
--recurse-paths
    Travel the directory structure recursively
```

When you are running the following command:

```
zip -ur zipfile.zip /
```

zip tries to compress the entire files in the system (from root `/` and below).

zip uses a temporary file (in your case you called it "garbage file") which holds the data it gather so far. Once the zip operation completed zip moves this temporary file to the resulted zip file.

In your case, you requested zip to compress all files in your system, which includes also the temporary file created by zip.

This might cause endless loop, as zip might try to add the temporary file to itself.

Also, you might try to add devices under `/dev` folder and similar files which I'm not sure that you would like to zip them.

Comment: Hey, ok it is my fault, basically i am not backing up a root directory but a volume and saving the zip file on another volume. So no, it is not going through the same "garbage files". I am sorry for not clarifying the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's four years later but I'm going to answer the question anyways. I do believe the swap file is getting stuck in a loop. `zip` creates the swap file in whichever dir its ran from, so here's the solution:

- I'd make any dir anywhere on the computer for example `/zip/` and navigate into it
- Then run the zip command but add `-j /zip/` or wherever your zip dir is so that it specifically does not touch anything there, including the deadly swap file.
- The full command would end up looking like

```
zip -ur zipfile.zip /volume1 -j /zip/
```

This would all work in a python script too if you either do

```py
os.chdir("/zip/")
```

or just run it from there in the first place. As far as I'm aware you don't have the option of deciding where the swap file goes manually.